# Woocommerce update price from external source

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have issue with updating of product price from external database. I need to check price of product in every access to this position. For that I use **the_post** hook. For example I got '1718' price value for single product.

```
function chd_the_post_action( $post ) {
    if ( $post && $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );  
        if ( $product ) {
            $price = '1718';
            $product->set_price( "$price" );    
            $product->set_regular_price( "$price" );    
            $product->set_sale_price( "$price" );    
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

This code update product price in database, but it's not change view of price on page in the same moment, but only after page reload because post and product variables was setup by **setup_postdata()**.
Therefore I use woocommerce hook for display updated price:

```
function chd_get_price_filter( $price, $item ) {
    return '1718';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'chd_get_price_filter', 100, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'chd_get_price_filter', 100, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'chd_get_price_filter', 100, 2 );
```

Is there any hook in which I can do this action in better way?

Comment: Try action 'post_submitbox_misc_actions' for chd_the_post_action().

Comment: It is also incorrect to do $product->set_price() as WooCommerce will automatically calculate price from regular_price and sale_price using the sale from/to dates. It will ignore anything you set here.

Comment: @user8262086 post_submitbox_misc_actions action actual for administration part of shop. I need to update price when somebody visit page with product

Comment: Try add_action( 'the_post', 'chd_the_post_action', 9); 9 so you run first.

Comment: Alternatively, put a global $product in your chd_the_post_action() as your code only really updates the database but the global $product which was created earlier from the original database stays the same. The global will prevent the global $product from becoming stale.

Comment: @user8262086 changing priority of hook to 9 is work, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_action( 'the_post', 'chd_the_post_action', 9, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Update product price using update_post_meta function like this

```
update_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price', '1718' );
update_post_meta( $product->id, '_regular_price', '1718 );
```

Comment: It's the same commands to $product->set_price( "$price" ); and also doesn't cause price value change on page instanly, only after page reload.

Comment: Although, this may work it is best not to directly update the database. In general you should use the API $product->set_XXX() because depending on the field WooCoommerce will do some consistency checks and automatically update the related fields accordlingly.

Comment: Actually, this will not work as the field '_price' which is calculated from '_sale_price' and '_regular_price' will not be updated. However, if you use the API, WooCommerce will automatically recalculate '_price' and save it to the table 'wp_postmeta'.